# Isomorphism between complex numbers minus zero and unit circle

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do we show that $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ and $S^{1}$ are isomorphic as groups?

Comment: They aren't. Do you mean $\mathbb{C}^\times$ and $S^1\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ (where $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is the positive real numbers under multiplciation)?

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: This is page 662, corollary 9.29 in Rotman's book (Advanced Modern Algebra). The proof is there (just trying to show it from first principles).

Comment: @user10: I see that you're right, Rotman is making this claim. I know for a fact that $\mathbb{C}^\times \cong S^1\times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, but I don't think that that alone would rule out the possibility that also $\mathbb{C}^\times\cong S^1$ (it would seem peculiar though). Still, I'm inclined to believe the book over myself on this, I'm too rusty with divisible groups and whatnot. Hopefully someone can come along and clear it up.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: thanks though, may I ask, what makes you think they aren't isomorphic?

Comment: @Zev: S^1 ≅ S^1 × R.  Basically S^1 is Q/Z × V where V is a zillion dimensional vector space over Q.  The logarithm takes the positive reals under multiplication to the additive reals.

Comment: Simply that $\mathbb{C}^\times$ has an "extra dimension", the radius, that $S^1$ doesn't. However, I'm starting to get an idea of how they might be isomorphic. I think that $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ just adds on $c$ more copies of $\mathbb{Q}$, which doesn't change anything. I doubt that there will be a formula describing the isomorphism $\mathbb{C}^\times\cong S^1$, since it will involve taking a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $\mathbb{R}$ or something like that.

Comment: @Jack: That makes sense, thanks for helping me out. user10, sorry for doubting :)

Comment: @user10: I'm out of votes for today, but I'll make sure I come back and give you +1 when it resets.

Comment: I suppose I can take some amount of solace in the fact that 3 other people had a similar incorrect intuition :)

Comment: There's a proof in the Wikipedia article on the circle group (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group#Group_structure) using the structure theorem for divisible groups.

Comment: The key to my confusion here is that you are asking about a *group* isomorphism and not a *topological* isomorphism (aka homeomorphism).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First, note that the additive groups of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are isomorphic, since $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the same dimension as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$.

In particular, there exists a group isomorphism $\varphi\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\varphi(1) = (1,0)$.  Then $\varphi(\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$, so
$$
S^1 \;\cong\; \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \;\cong\; \mathbb{R}^2/(\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}) \;\cong\; S^1\times\mathbb{R} \;\cong\; \mathbb{C}^\times.
$$

Comment: I like the way you nicely compartmentalize the insane part of it into R = R^2.

Comment: @gary that map is not a bijection.

Comment: Wouldn't the map h: z->z/||z|| do it? $h(z_1.z_2)$:= $z_1.z_2/||z1_.z_2||$= $(z_1/||z_1||)(z_2/||z_2||)$ ; kernel is trivial, and map is onto.

Comment: @wckronholm: where does it fail? The kernel is trivial. Is it not onto, then?

Comment: @gary, the kernel is not trivial, it is all $z$ such that $z/|z|=1$, that is, all of $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @Thomas: ouch, you're right. I was only thinking of the kernel of z1.z2, forgetting that we were dividing by the norm. A highschool-level mistake!@ Every line thru (0,0) is collapsed into the point (1,m)/$Sqr(1+m^2)$ , for points in (x,mx).

Comment: And this is yet another reason why some have trouble with non-constructive mathematics.

Comment: @wnoise:what are you referring to by "this"?

Answer (score 11):

Every divisible abelian group is equal to the direct sum of its torsion part and of a $\mathbb Q$-vector space : $$A=Tors(A) \oplus V$$

In the situation at hand, the torsion part of both groups under study is the denumerable group $\mu_\infty (\mathbb C)$ of roots of unity and we deduce 
$$\mathbb C^\times= \mu_\infty (\mathbb C)\oplus  V   \quad  \quad  S^1=    \mu_\infty (\mathbb C)  \oplus  W        $$
Since for cardinality reasons $V$ and $W$ have continuous dimension , they are isomorphic and so are our groups $\mathbb C^\times$ and $ S^1$ .

**Terminology** In the multiplicative notation, an element $a\in A$ of an abelian  group is said to be torsion if $a^n=1$ for some positive integer $n$.

**Remark** Jim's answer has the charm of being direct and  slick. However some users might like the fact that the  present solution  is a simple application  of the general structure theorem for divisible abelian groups. That  theorem, and much, much more, is to be found in Kaplanski's elegant booklet (90 pages!) *Infinite Abelian Groups*.