# Does the algebraic structure of a Lie group restrict the possible dimensions of other Lie groups isomorphic to it?

Tags: lie-groups

In a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44454/isomorphism-between-complex-numbers-minus-zero-and-unit-circle), I initially doubted that $\mathbb{C}^\times\cong S^1$, my intuition being that $\mathbb{C}^\times$ has one more "dimension" than $S^1$ - in rigorous terms, $S^1$ is (or rather, can be given the structure of) a 1-dimensional Lie group, and $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is (can be given the structure of) a 2-dimensional Lie group.

My question is rather naive: Given a Lie group $G$ of dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, for which $m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ does there exist a Lie group $H$ of dimension $m$ such that $G\cong H$ **as groups** (forgetting about the manifold structure)? Surely there is at least one $G$ such that the answer isn't *all* $m$?

Comment: I guess your question is motivated by the fact that for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, you have a group ($\mathbb{Q}$-vector space) isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^n \simeq \mathbb{R}^m$, right ?

Comment: I had also thought about that while composing the question, but I was mainly motivated by my incorrect intuition about $\mathbb{C}^\times\cong S^1$.

Comment: Still informally, re the dimension issue, $C^x$ is homotopic to $S^1$, by retraction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe all 1-dimensional (connected) real lie groups are abelian, so given a non-abelian lie group there exists no lie group of dimension 1 isomorphic to it.

Answer (score 3):

A related question was asked at  [MathOverflow.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65897/which-groups-admit-a-unique-lie-group-structure) The author argues that there is a unique Lie group structure on $SU(2)$.